# Why curve modifiers deform my mesh

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

I have this: a plane, as you can see.

[image]

Object mode:

[image]

And a Curve:

[image]

When I try to create a rolling mat effect, using the curve modifiers, the plan is deform like this:

[image]

[image]

What I want is to keep the mat dimensions. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the radius of each control point of your curve and set them to 1. You can select all of them and set the "mean radius".

Most likely you scaled down or up your curve then applied the transform. This actually keeps the curve at the same position but changes the radius of each control point.

[image]

**Note** : You can deactivate the use of the radius of control points altogether by toggling "radius" in the curve properties. That means any deformation using this curve will consider every control point with a radius of 1 :

[image]

Comment: I'm not the OP, but thanks for the explanation! I finally understand why sometimes my *mean radius* is at 200, even though it should go only up to 100.

Comment: Yes that's a bit confusing. I have added additional info if you want to keep the small "V" lines along the resolution points when playing with a small curve. just deactivate the "radius" checkbutton in the curve settings.

Comment: Thanks @Gorgious! Your the man!!!!